# Appending an Object Without A Link

Tags: python, scripting, import, append

**What:**

I am trying to append an object in a .blend file using.

**How:**

```
TheObject="SINGLEBATTWIRE"
Thepath="B:/........../SINGLEBATTWIRE.blend/Object/SINGLEBATTWIRE"
Thedirectory="B:/........../SINGLEBATTWIRE.blend/Object/"

bpy.ops.wm.link_append(link=False, filepath=Thepath, 
directory=Thedirectory, filename=TheObject)
```

**Problem:**

The import works fine, but it is linked and can’t be moved.
This is the result I get.

[image]

**Current Resolutions:**

If I click the button beside the objects name it fixes the problem, but I need to append many objects and this would take forever.
If I go to File-Append and find the object, it works great and I have this result.

[image]

Comment: what version you are using , I think `link_append()` has been replaced by `link()` and `append` ?!

Comment: I am using version 2.70a. Link is not included. Are you suggesting an update and use the new append function?

Comment: I have tried Link() and append() before with no problem (just a simple test ), so If you have no reason to stick with that version , why not ?

Comment: Trying now....!

Comment: @Chebhou - Post that as an answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bpy.ops.wm.link_append()` function has been replaced by the two `link()` and `append()` functions and they can be used the same way :
Example :

```
import bpy

directory = "C:/folder/myfile.blend/Object/"
objname ='Cube'

bpy.ops.wm.append(directory=directory, filename=objname, link=False)
```